# How to access session variables across multiple controllers in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, controller

I have implemented a facebook connect for my application. So when a user logs in I wish to store his facebook id in the session and use it across multiple controllers and views. I tried implementing this . I also referred to several similar questions answered in stackoverflow . However something seems wrong. I set the facebook id in the session in the UserController . I am not able to access it in the EventsController.

The flow is :  When the user logins in for the first time . The fbinsertupdate is called. And then the page redirects to events#index page.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

 def self.current=(u)
@current_user = u
end

def self.current
@current_user
end


end





class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery



  # Finds the User with the ID stored in the session with the key
  # :fb_user_id 

  def current_user
    User.current  ||= session[:fb_user_id] &&
      User.find(session[:fb_user_id])
  end


end




class UsersController < ApplicationController



  def fbinsertupdate  #Facebook connect. Insert new user or update existing user


    @user = User.find_or_create_by_fbid(params[:fbid]) 
    @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
    session[:fb_user_id] = @user.fbid  # storing the facebook id in the session
    render :nothing => true




  end



end


class EventsController < ApplicationController

  def index
     @events = Event.all
     @current_user= User.current
    logger.debug "The current user is  "+@current_user.name  # This fails . Says the class in nil

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @events }
    end
  end


end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a `before_filter` missing? You do not seem to call the `current_user` method at all (that reads the session). I see two ways to correct this:

Either use a `before_filter`: at the top of your `EventsController` write

```
class EventsController < ApplicationController

  before_filter :current_user 

  def index
    @events = Event.all
    @current_user= User.current
    logger.debug "The current user is  "+@current_user.name  # This fails . Says the class in nil

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @events }
    end
  end
end
```

or, you change your `index`-code as follows:

```
  def index
    @events = Event.all
    @current_user= current_user
    logger.debug "The current user is  "+@current_user.name  # This fails . Says the class in nil

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @events }
    end
  end
```

Note that if you are using an API, using rest/soap, that there is no session and that you will have to return information (e.g. xml or json), that then could be handed along in the next call.

Comment: Hi , I made changes as recommended by you. But ,this still fails . I tried printing the session variable inside userscontroller. It prints it fine. But the same variable is not accessible inside the ApplicationController. It turns out to be nil inside ApplicationController.

Comment: Hi, i am not sure how your facebook application works, but if it is using an API to access your rails application, then each call has its own session. If that is not the case, i would look at your session-store?

Comment: Hi there is just a single facebook connect. So the facebook api is used only once- the first time  . I fetch the user details from facebook and then call  users#fbinsertupdate  . It then redirects to events#index . The session store is as below Alpha1::Application.config.session_store :cookie_store, :key => '_alpha1_session'

Comment: I tried printing the session id in both controllers . In users controller ( where I write the session variable ) and users controller ( where I try to fetch the value ) . Both seem to have different session ids.                      logger.debug "session id" + session[:session_id]